# Probability of getting 2 odd numbers with 2 dice in a row?

Tags: probability

I have 2 ordinary 6 sided dice, I throw the pair of dice twice, what is the probability that I get an odd number on both throws?

What I know is that if there is only 1 round the players getting the probability is that

```
All players get 5 = 16 out of 1,679,616
All players get 7 = 400 out of 1,679,616
All players get 9 = 3,136 out of 1,679,616
All players get 11 = 10,816 out of 1,679,616

2 players get 3 = 4 out of 1,296
2 players get 5 = 16 out of 1,296
2 players get 7 = 36 out of 1,296
2 players get 9 = 16 out of 1,296
2 players get 11 = 4 out of 1,296

3 players get 3 = 1 out of 1,296
3 players get 5 = 12 out of 1,296
3 players get 7 = 30 out of 1,296
3 players get 9 = 625 out of 1,296
3 players get 11 = 648 out of 1,296
```

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: When you say get an odd number, do you mean on one die or the total.  Would a roll of  $1,3$ mean you got an odd number?  What is the point of all the text below "What I know"?  How does it apply to the question?

Answer (score 1):

The set of all outcomes is:

${\Big\{\big((1,1),(1,1)\big), \ldots, \big((1,1),(1,6)\big),\big((1,1),(2,1)\big),\ldots,\big((6,6),(6,5)\big),\big((6,6),(6,6)\big)\Big\}}.$

How many tuples does this set include and how many of these tuples include an odd number in the first and in the second throw?

Comment: The set of outcomes for throwing *two* die, *twice*, is $$(\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}^2)^2= {\Big\{\big((1,1),(1,1)\big), \ldots, \big((1,1),(1,6)\big),\big((1,1),(2,1)\big),\ldots,\big((6,6),(6,5)\big),\big((6,6),(6,6)\big)\Big\}}$$ and we are looking for the event of at least one odd number in each of the inner pairs.

Comment: That's true - I misread the question and edited my post with your set.